# How to convert few line batch script to perl script

Tags: sql, perl, batch-file

I am new in perl script. Can you please suggest me how to convert few lines of batch script into perl script.

My batch script is :

```
:: delete *.bak file from store_id Patel General

del "D:\Database\Patel General Store\*.bak"

:: change Directory 

cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

:: extract new data from drop box to database folder

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"\7z.exe  -o"D:\Database\Patel General Store\" e "D:\Dropbox\Database Backup\Patel General Store\*"
d

:: Rename new .bak data with storelocation_storeid_store_na

cd\

rename "D:\Database\Patel General Store\*.bak" MUM_099_Patel_General_Stores_30.bak

cd\


sqlcmd -S"ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS" -E -Q "restore database MUM_099_Patel_General_Stores_30 from disk='D:\Database\Patel General Store\MUM_099_Patel_General_Stores_30.bak' with move 'Account180001' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\MUM_099_Patel_General_Stores_30.mdf',Move 'Account180001_LOG' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\MUM_099_Patel_General_Stores_30_Log.ldf',replace"
```

If new store added then I need to copy all line and paste one more time. It is all hard coded,will please suggest some thing so that I will free from this hard coding

Comment: You certainly have tried anything. Why wouldn't you post this so that we can use this as a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

use `system()` call from perl.

i.e put the above commands in a batch file say xyz.bat
and from perl use

`system("xyz.bat");`
`presuming xyz.bat` is in your perl directory. The control will return to your perl script after executing the commands.

If you do not want to return to the calling perl script...use 'exec' instead as follows..

`exec("xyz.bat");`

Happy computing............

Comment: Thank you for your reply.but I want remove hard code lines in batch script, because these line repeated so many time.